# Regex: Ensure minimum number of line breaks in a textarea input

Tags: php, regex, yii, preg-match, line-breaks

I currently have a text area as an input field and want to ensure it has more than 3 separate lines.

As I am using the Yii framework, I am using the validate() method for validating against a model.

With the validation being done by Yii, I was intending to use match functionality to check using regular expressions that the input is valid.

Currently I have:

```
    array('ingredients', 'match', 'pattern'=> '/(\n|\r\n|\r){3,}/'),
```

Which doesn't work, however if I change the 3 to a 1 it works correctly.

How can I ensure that there are at least 3 lines using regex?

Comment: `substr_count($string, "\n") >= 3` seems to make much more sense to me. I'm sure Yii allows for custom validation functions like this.

Comment: Three lines are two breaks (not three).

Comment: @deceze I was planning to check that, however Yii framework has been inaccessible all day.

Comment: @hakre Good point, although with 4 lines it still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three lines are two breaks, not three. So the number you're looking for is 2.

Then regular expressions match the first first. So you should use `\r\n` as the first subpattern to prevent catching `\n\r` as a sequence of two line-breaks.

Then you look for repeated line-breaks. But you want to allow more than just empty lines.

Probably this pattern will fit your needs:

```
/^(?:.*(?:\r\n|\n|\r)){2,}/
```

It will allow three or more (empty and non-empty) lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression

```
/(\n|\r\n|\r){3,}/
```

would mean that there are three consecutive line breaks. Allow some other characters in between, e.g.

```
/((\n|\r\n|\r).*){3,}/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the contents of those lines as well:

```
array('ingredients', 'match', 'pattern'=> '/(.*(\n|\r\n|\r)){3,}/'),
```